# Why local trace function shows line event for a function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace, sys

I was trying to understand how functions can be traced by following the code mentioned in [this article](https://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html#tracing-inside-functions).

```py
import sys

def trace_lines(frame, event, arg):
    if event != 'line':
        return
    co = frame.f_code
    func_name = co.co_name
    line_no = frame.f_lineno
    filename = co.co_filename
    print(f"{func_name} line {line_no}")

def trace_calls(frame, event, arg):
    if event != 'call':
        return
    co = frame.f_code
    func_name = co.co_name
    if func_name == 'write':
        # Ignore write() calls from print statements
        return
    line_no = frame.f_lineno
    filename = co.co_filename
    print(f"Call to {func_name} on line {line_no} of {filename}")
    if func_name in TRACE_INTO:
        # Trace into this function
        return trace_lines
    return

def c(input):
    print('input =', input)
    print('Leaving c()')

def b(arg):
    val = arg * 5
    c(val)
    print('Leaving b()')

def a():
    b(2)
    print('Leaving a()')
    
TRACE_INTO = ['b']

sys.settrace(trace_calls)
a()
```

Upon running this program, this is the output that we get:

```bash
$ python3 test.py
Call to a on line 37 of /Users/xyz/personal/projects/test.py
Call to b on line 32 of /Users/xyz/personal/projects/test.py
b line 33
b line 34
Call to c on line 28 of /Users/xyz/personal/projects/test.py
input = 10
Leaving c()
b line 35
Leaving b()
Leaving a()
```

Looking at the program, the first two lines of the output are straightforward. The function `a()` is called which calls function `b()`. For `b()`, a local trace function named `trace_lines()` is used.

Since the first line in the definition of function `b()` is an expression, it is treated as a `line` event and therefore, the `b line 33` is printed.

But the second line in function `b()` is a function call to `c()` and not an expression. So I was expecting it to be a `call` event. Since the local trace function for function `b()` is `trace_lines()`, it should have returned because of the failure of the first condition `if event != 'line'`. But here, for a function call to `c()`, the output first shows a `line` event to `trace_lines()` and then a `call` event to `trace_calls()`.

```
b line 34
Call to c on line 28 of /Users/xyz/personal/projects/test.py
```

If this is how it works for every function call, Every encounter of a function call should have looked like this-

**Step 1:** Pass it as a `line` event
**Step 2:** Once it is identified as a function, pass a `call` event to global trace function.

Here is my question-
Why a line event is generated for the function call to `c()` before the actual `call` event to global trace function? Also It would be great if somebody can break this output down with explanation.

Comment: **Since the first line in the definition of function b() is an expression,** -- No, it's not.  That's true in C, but in Python, assignments are statements, not expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're confused that you'd get a "line" event before the "call".  The interpreter has to start interpreting line 34 before it knows there's going to be a function call.

Comment: @TimRoberts If that is the case, interpreter should have shown line events for function calls of both function a() and b(). But it only showed call events for them upon debugging.

Comment: But you are telling it only to trace function 'b', right?  That's what your `TRACE_INTO` is doing.